# Why when I run jquery.post with serialized data that contains underscore, it got internal server error?

Tags: jquery, serialization

As title above, I execute jquery.post with serialized data that contains data __VIEWSTATE and it failed and raised error: internal server error. If I remove the double underscore, it sent normally. Even I replace the underscore with &5F still cannot work. Any one can help me?

This is the sample serialized data: `__VIEWSTATE=2FwEPDwUKMjA0MjMxNTU1OGRk3d3uA8978xJJp2BpibvGI2FYCqRgvt007Iub3qwQb9cKk3D&newFlag=1&cfunction=save&cfunctionlist=1BB57B21-04EC-4B89-87CE-DA10AAE9429E&csortAsc=&csortDesc=&csort=&ischangecombo=0&lastPageNo=6&PageSel=1&cid=1BB57B21-04EC-4B89-87CE-DA10AAE9429E&ParameterCode=11&ParameterDescription=11&SystemMode=`

Comment: Seems like you are using ASP.NET web forms, If you are posting to a different page in ASP.Net and passing `__ViewState`, the handlers in ASp.Net pipeline tries to validate the submitted ViewState (which does not validates for any other page) and when that does not matches it throws server error.